# Grails 2.5.x GORM Hibernate 4.3.8.1 PostgreSQL rlike

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

How do I implement rlike for Grails GORM Hibernate PostgreSQL? When I submit my query via Domain.executeQuery(query, parameters) I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '~' ...
```

I am building the query String like:

```
"and ((lower(foo.name) rlike :fooTag) or (lower(foo.summary) rlike :fooTag)) "
```

When I searched for `rlike` I found a couple of comments indicating only MySQL and Oracle are supported by Hibernate. Can I add support for PostgreSQL? If yes how?

Comment: why don't you use the plain `like`?

Comment: I want to do a regular expression search on a PostgreSQL DB. PostgreSQL supports regular expression queries with the ~ character.